# How can I request the relationships of a resource without using a filter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a backend that follows the JSON API specification.

In my Ember app, I do something like this:

```
model() {
  return this.store.query('category', { filter: { forum: 'main' } });
}
```

This works well and the request sent to the server is `GET /categories?filter[forum]=main`. My app gets all the categories from the forum with ID `main`.

Now, instead of the previous request, I would like to make a `GET /forums/main/categories` from the model. How can this be done in Ember with Ember Data?

Here's something I tried with Ember AJAX:

```
ajax: Ember.inject.service(),

model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    categories: this.get('ajax').request('/forums/main/categories'),
  });
}
```

The request works and the correct data is returned from the server. But Ember Data just doesn't know about it and I can't use the model in my template. How can I make Ember AJAX work with Ember Data?

The Ember AJAX GitHub page proposes to write something like that:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import AjaxServiceSupport from 'ember-ajax/mixins/ajax-support';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(AjaxServiceSupport);
```

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax#usage-with-ember-data

But it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: you can create model specific adapter and configure `namespace` properties to `forums/main`

Comment: `main` is an ID. That won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, `/forums/main/categories` looks a bit like a relationship link. Like `forum` is a model as well, and has a relationship categories. Is this right?

If yes, probably the best thing is to first fetch the `forum` and then the relationship. Maybe you already have the `forum` record? So something like this:

```
store.findRecord('forum', 'main').then(forum => forum.get('categories'));
```

However if you want to filter the `categories` based on a forum string, this is also possible. So basically you want to do this:

```
this.store.query('category', { filter: { forum: 'main' } });
```

But it should request `/forums/main/categories` instead of `/categories?filter[forum]=main`. This can be done with a custom adapter. Probably you just have to override `urlForQuery`:

```
urlForQuery(query, modelName) {
  if(query.filter.forum)
    const forum = query.filter.forum;
    delete query.filter.forum;
    return `/forums/${forum}/categories`
  } else {
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
},
```

Comment: I am looking for something like `store.findRecord('forum', 'main').then(forum => forum.get('categories'));`. I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It only makes a `GET /forums/main`.

Comment: does `/forums/main` respond with a correct JSONAPI response and a `links` object on the relationship?

Comment: Yes. When I try to use `forum.categories` in the template, it automatically makes a `GET /forum/main/categories`, but it's not convenient. I can't apply a filter, sort the data, etc. That's why I'd like the request to happen in a route where I have more control over it.